# Capturing and manipulating microphone audio with AVCaptureSession?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, microphone, avcapturesession

While there are plenty of tutorials for how to use AVCaptureSession to grab camera data, I can find no information (even on apple's dev network itself) on how to properly handle microphone data.

I have implemented AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate, and I'm getting calls to my delegate, but I have no idea how the contents of the CMSampleBufferRef I get are formatted. Are the contents of the buffer one discrete sample? What are its properties? Where can these properties be set?

Video properties can be set using [AVCaptureVideoDataOutput setVideoSettings:], but there is no corresponding call for AVCaptureAudioDataOutput (no setAudioSettings or anything similar).

Comment: Have you seen the code for the "Wavy" app from WWDC 2010.  It gets the microphone data and plots its on the screen in real time.

Comment: No, I have not, nor have I been able to find a copy of it. What Audio lib/frameworks did it use? Is it possible to set the sampling rate and make use of the phone's hardware encoders when sampling mic data?

Answer (score 1):

They are formatted as LPCM! You can verify this by getting the AudioStreamBasicDescription like so:

```
CMFormatDescriptionRef formatDescription = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(sampleBuffer);
const AudioStreamBasicDescription *streamDescription = CMAudioFormatDescriptionGetStreamBasicDescription(formatDescription);
```

and then checking the stream description’s mFormatId.